# VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS for username, password and role

Tags: python, dashboard

Previously, I only have username and password, so I make it
from this:

```
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD = {"abc": "abc", "welcome": "world"}
```

to this:

```
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD_PAIRS = df_userpwd.set_index('username')['password'].to_dict()
```

Currently, I have a list of username with password and role.

```
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD = {"test": {"password":"test", "role":"admin"}, "hello": {"password":"world", "role":"user"}}
```

So, if all the information is store in dataframe, how can I extract it from csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my app.py has `.get` function, therefore, the below solution is workable for me:

pwd.csv

| username | password | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test | test | admin |
| hello | world | user |

code:

```
VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD= pd.read_csv("pwd.csv").set_index('username').transpose().to_dict()


>>> {"test": {"password":"test", "role":"admin"}, "hello": {"password":"world", "role":"user"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `.to_csv()` function.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD)
>>>
>>> df
           test  hello
password   test  world
role      admin   user
>>> 
>>> df.to_csv('creds.csv')
>>>
```

That's modeled as 2 rows with N columns for N users.
Much more convenient to model it using N rows:

```
>>> df.transpose()
      password   role
test      test  admin
hello    world   user
```

---

You can [.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and then .transpose():

```
>>> pd.read_csv("creds.csv")
   username   test  hello
0  password   test  world
1      role  admin   user
>>> 
>>> df = pd.read_csv("creds.csv").set_index('username').transpose()
>>> df
username password   role
test         test  admin
hello       world   user
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pp
>>> 
>>> pp(df.to_dict())
{'password': {'test': 'test', 'hello': 'world'},
 'role': {'test': 'admin', 'hello': 'user'}}
>>>
```

Comment: but I am referring to `dash_auth.BasicAuth`

Comment: If your question cited the Dash docs then I must have missed the reference.

Comment: but i will get error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` because I have `if VALID_USERNAME_PASSWORD.get(username) is None:` in my app.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It is clear that there is some problem you are trying to solve. It is not yet clear to me what it is, nor what success criteria we'd put on a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would be very helpful to SO contributors if you could phrase the details in terms of a ("red") failing [unit test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase), so we can experiment with proposed solutions before posting them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer If you find (even a partial) solution, please post.